# How do I convert nested ternary operator to nested if-else statements?

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement, ternary

I'm having a hard time trying to convert the following C# code into a if-else statement, so that I can understand the business logic. Can anybody help me, checking whether my conversion is ok?

**Code:**

```
dateInit = objInstance == null ? (DateTime?)null:
                objInstance.DateAnt == null ?
                    objInstance.DatePost > otherObjInstance.DateCon ?
                        (DateTime?)null :
                        objInstance.DatePost :
                objInstance.DateAnt;
```

**My conversion:**

```
if (objInstance == null)
{
    dateInit = (DateTime?)null;
}
else
{
    if (objInstance.DateAnt == null)
    {
        if (objInstance.DatePost > otherObjInstance.DateCon)
        {
            dateInit = (DateTime?)null;
        }
        else
        {
            dateInit = objInstance.DatePost;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dateInit = objInstance.DataAnt;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be a better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: this is not code review...

Comment: @Igor This would get closed within minutes on CR. Please check their help center before you recommend another site. See also https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: You convert it the right way

Comment: I don't see why this question is closed; it seems to me to be a practical question about real code that has an answer.

Comment: I will try to edit to get it to be acceptable

Comment: @PedroCoelho I recommend that you make a console app, where you can make a test case that echos the structure of your problem phrase and see if evaluates the same way for both your ternary and if-else code. I make bunches of such micro-apps all the time

Comment: Thank you, Clay. I've started contributing to stack overflow recently and I'm not enterely into formalistic issues on questions. I will check how you will edit it to see how I can improve for next times. Anyway, I imagine the idea here is to help and be helped, so I hope no one downvotes or closes this question merely due to formalistic issues.

Comment: FYI, Resharper (and probably other refactor tools) could convert between the two variants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conversion appears to be correct. However, I would improve it in two ways.

First, the casts on `null` are unnecessary in the `if` form. (The `?:` operator has certain restrictions on the types that can appear in the consequence and alternative positions, which leads to developers inserting casts.)

Second, the `if` statements are unnecessarily nested. The whole thing could be expressed much more readably as:

```
if (objInstance == null)
  dateInit = null;
else if (objInstance.DateAnt != null)
  dateInit = objInstance.DataAnt;
else if (objInstance.DatePost > otherObjInstance.DateCon)
  dateInit = null;
else
  dateInit = objInstance.DatePost;
```

The business logic is more understandable from this version than your version I think.

We can make this transformation using two rules. First:

```
if (x)
  X
else 
{
  if (y)
    Y
  else
    Z
}
```

is the same as

```
if (x)
  X
else if (y)
  Y
else
  Z
```

Which is simpler on the page.

And second:

```
if (x)
{
  if (y)
    Y
  else
    Z
}
else
  NX
```

is the same as

```
if (!x)
  NX
else 
{
  if (y)
    Y
  else
    Z
}
```

And now we're in the first case again and can simplify further.

By repeatedly combining these rules you can simplify a lot of complicated `if-else` statements.